# GeoServer with printing plugin, scale too low

Tags: geoserver, mapfish

GeoServer 2.8.1, printing plugin to PDF

[image: what I got]

On scale 10000 picture of WMS layer is too low scale.  As in legend and on normal map it is 300 meters.
But those red dots - it mirrors of all objects, on 7 earths, very low scale, normal view looks like this:

[image: good scale]

Something wrong with scale, but can't understand what.

Config is easy:

```
#===========================================================================
# allowed DPIs
#===========================================================================
dpis: [75, 90, 150, 300]

#===========================================================================
# the allowed scales
#===========================================================================
scales:
  - 1
  - 50
  - 1000
  - 5000
  - 10000
  - 25000
  - 50000
  - 100000
  - 200000
  - 500000
  - 1000000
  - 2000000
  - 4000000

layouts:
  Legal:
    mainPage:
      pageSize: A4
      landscape: true
      items:
        - !map
          spacingAfter: 0
          width: 800
          height: 500
        - !scalebar
          maxSize: 150
```

Answer (score 1):

I got answer.

As in Mapfish docs, 
"The **geodetic** parameter can be set to true so the scale of geodetic layers can correctly be calculated. Certain projections (Google and **Latlong** for example) are based on a spheroid and therefore require geodetic: **true** in order to correctly calculate the scale. If the geodetic parameter is not present it will be assumed to be false."

So with adding this to request, picture is normal.

```
pages: [
        {
            center: [6, 45.5],
            scale: 1000,
            dpi: 190,
            geodetic: true
```

Comment: but i have problem
http://puu.sh/lV4uq/923d051461.png
proportions wrong, it must be dot, circle, but in PDF i got oval

Comment: answer - another crs, after use of EPSG:3395 proportion is OK