# Wrong scale on printed PDF on Mapfish print

Tags: pdf, scale, mapfish, mapfish-print

I have a problem with printing layers on concrete scale. For example, I send request as below:

```
{
   "layout":"A4 portrait",
   "outputFormat":"pdf",
   "outputFilename":"test",
   "attributes":{
      "label":"",
      "description":"",
      "madeBy":"",
      "notes":"",
      "copyright":"<div class=\"copyrightIframe\">  © OpenStreetMap Contributors;</div> ",
      "madeIn":"",
      "mmVersion":"",
      "datasource":[
         {
            "table":{
               "data":[
                 
               ],
               "columns":[
                 
               ]
            },
            "displayName1":"",
            "displayName2":"",
            "displayName3":"",
            "isParcel":0,
            "isMap":1,
            "map":{
               "dpi":"96",
               "rotation":0,
               "center":[
                  1960176.3323157998,
                  6168869.777743851
               ],
               "scale":7000,
               "layers":[
                  {
                     "type":"osm",
                     "baseURL":"http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                     "opacity":1,
                     "maxExtent":[
                        -20037508.342789244,
                        -20037508.342789244,
                        20037508.342789244,
                        20037508.342789244
                     ],
                     "tileSize":[
                        256,
                        256
                     ],
                     "resolutions":[
                        156543.03390625,
                        78271.516953125,
                        39135.7584765625,
                        19567.87923828125,
                        9783.939619140625,
                        4891.9698095703125,
                        2445.9849047851562,
                        1222.9924523925781,
                        611.4962261962891,
                        305.74811309814453,
                        152.87405654907226,
                        76.43702827453613,
                        38.218514137268066,
                        19.109257068634033,
                        9.554628534317017,
                        4.777314267158508,
                        2.388657133579254,
                        1.194328566789627,
                        0.5971642833948135,
                        0.29858214169740677,
                        0.14929107084870338,
                        0.07464553542435169,
                        0.037322767712175846,
                        0.018661383856087923,
                        0.009330691928043961,
                        0.004665345964021981,
                        0.0023326729820109904,
                        0.0011663364910054952,
                        0.0005831682455027476,
                        0.0002915841227513738
                     ],
                     "imageExtension":"png"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ],
      "legendOnPage":0,
      "printParcelInfo":0,
      "iconLeft":"images/logo.png",
      "iconRight":""
   }
}
```

The scale is set to "scale":7000.

However, after printing PDF on paper, distance is as it was set to scale. 1:5000. I have measured lines on paper and figured out that the scale is not good at all.

I have tried to solve the problem with attribute “geodetic”: true, as is recommended on these two pages:

[Geoserver MapFish print : wrong scale and scalebar on my printed map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218015/geoserver-mapfish-print-wrong-scale-and-scalebar-on-my-printed-map)

[GeoServer with printing plugin, scale too low](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173678/geoserver-with-printing-plugin-scale-too-low)

but, unfortunately with no luck.

In configuration file, my set up for a4 is:

```
templates:
#===========================================================================
  A4 portrait: !template
  #===========================================================================
    reportTemplate: A4Portrait.jrxml
    tableData: jrDataSource
    outputFilename: ${outputFilename}
    attributes:
      iconLeft: !string {}
      iconRight: !string {}
      madeBy: !string {}
      madeIn: !string {}
      mmVersion: !string {}
      label: !string {}
      description: !string {}
      notes: !string {}
      copyright: !string {}
      legendCols: !integer
        default: 3
      datasource: !datasource
        attributes:
          table: !table {}
          isParcel: !integer {}
          isMap: !integer {}
          displayName1: !string {}
          displayName2: !string {}
          displayName3: !string {}
          map: !map
            maxDpi: 450
            dpiSuggestions: [90,96,150,300]
            width: 570
            height: 696
          scalebar: !scalebar
            width: 240
            height: 30
            createSubReport: false
            default:
              barBgColor: rgba(0,0,0,0)
              align: "left"
          northArrowDef: !northArrow
            size: 50
            createSubReport: false
            default:
              graphic: "images/gm-north.png"
      legendOnPage: !integer {}
      printParcelInfo: !integer {}
    processors:
    - !reportBuilder # compile all reports in current directory
      directory: '.'
    - !configureHttpRequests
      httpProcessors:
        - !forwardHeaders
          headers: [Referer, User-Agent, Cookie, Authorization]
        - !addHeaders
          headers: 
            User-Agent: ${customUserAgent}
            Referer: ${customReferer}
    - !createDataSource
      reportTemplate: A4PortraitLegend.jrxml
      reportKey: reportTemplate
      processors:
        - !prepareTable {}
        - !createMap {}
        - !createScalebar {}
        - !createNorthArrow
          inputMapper: {map: map, northArrowDef: northArrow}
    tableData: jrDataSource
    outputFilename: ${outputFilename}
    pdfConfig:
      title: test print
      subject: test print
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Nope, there is no solution for this kind of problem, because it is caused by projection 3857 and spherical representation of data on 2D printed PDF file. For more precise printing, it is required to use more accurate (local) projection.
https://epsg.io/3857
Take note on Remarks part.